# VisualStudio2017 で PyInstaller を使用したい

Tags: python, visual-studio, pyinstaller

Pythonで開発しているアプリをスタンドアローン実行するexeにしたく、Pyinstallerを使用したいと考えました。

**開発環境：**
OS：Windows10 Pro
IDE：Visual Studio 2017

Visual Studioのpython環境タブからパッケージを選択、`pip install pyinstaller` を実行し成功したメッセージがでました。
添付する＜python環境.jpg＞にpython環境タブを示しますが、インストールされているようです。
pypiwin32, pywin32 もインストールされていることを確認しました。

[image: Python環境]

インタラクティブウィンドウで、実行した結果が、＜pyinstaller実行.jpg＞です。

[image: Pythoninstaller実行]

ファイル名指定なしで実行すると、以下のように表示されるため、pyinstallerが正しく認識されていないのでしょうか。
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib\site-packages` というフォルダの中には `PyInstaller` というフォルダができています。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示をお願いいたします。

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pyinstaller' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyInstallerで.exeを作成する際に、インタラクティブウィンドウから実行する(下記のようにコマンドプロンプトから -mで実行と同じ？)場合は、大文字小文字の区別があるかもしれません。
**pyinstaller** ではなく、**PyInstaller** でやってみてください。

[Using pyinstaller with Visual Studio 2017](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/972274/using_pyinstaller_with_visual_studio_2017/)

> It looks like I already have it installed, but then the computer forgets? It says it has pyinstaller one second and then doesn't the next.
>
> ```
> C:\Users\blah\blah\blah>py -m pyinstaller --onefile my_script.py
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe: No module named pyinstaller
> ```
>
> To use the **-m** version you have to capitalize it differently. Try:
>
> ```
> py -m PyInstaller --onefile my_script.py
> ```
>
> That worked! Thank you.

あるいは、インタラクティブウィンドウではなく、Windowsのコマンドプロンプトで.exe化対象スクリプトのあるフォルダに移動し、`pyinstaller.exe`をフルパス指定して実行する方法もあるでしょう。(Python36_64とその下のScriptsフォルダの両方にPATHを通していれば、上記引用と同じコマンド実行でもできそうです)

上記リンクの途中の方：

> Try "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe" --onefile my_script.py then.
>
> That made a .exe! Thank you.

日本語の記事
[pythonスクリプトのEXE化](http://hiroys.hatenablog.jp/entry/2017/10/25/015929)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
py -m PyInstaller で実行したところ、動作しました。生成されたexeファイルは何か問題があるようで、動作しませんでしたが、これから詳しく見てみます。pyファイルだけで数十に上るので、依存関係など解決していかなくてはならないようです。

Comment: ちなみに、VisualStudioCodeで試してうまくいった状況です。VisualStudio2017ではうまくいきません。

Comment: 大概のことは、起動時のPATHが通っているかフルパスで指定したかの違いと、カレントフォルダが正しいか、あたりの状況でしょう。VSCodeは呼び出し時にそうした事前準備を行っていて、VS2017の方は特にケアしていないのでは？